# Yii and Image upload YUSH

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem that I simply don't know how or as a matter of fact what to solve. I'm using Yii and an extension called YUSH. This helps with folder structuring when uploading an image.

On my localhost everything works great. But now that I migrated to a live server, the filename still gets written to the database but a folder containing the uploaded file is not created. Thus only an image placeholder is displayed.

This isn't giving any error messages, so I really don't know how to fix it. My host has increased my mem_size in php.ini and I have checked all my error logs. Still nothing.

Here is my code:

```
$image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($l, 'path');
            if ($image)
            {
                // Clean up the filename
                $encName = md5($image->name . microtime()) . '.' . $image->extensionName;
                $l->path = $encName;
            }

        $l->merchant_id_fk = $this->getMerchantRelation(Yii::app()->user->id);

        switch ($l->validate()) {

                // User validate Successfull
                case TRUE:

                        if($l->save())
                        {

                            //Save Image
                            Yush::init($l);
                            // Nothing has been uploaded yet but YUSH will return a full path that can be used to save the resource
                            $originalPath = Yush::getPath($l, Yush::SIZE_ORIGINAL, $l->path);
                            // Save the original resource to disk
                            $image->saveAs($originalPath);
                            $thumbPath = Yush::getPath($l, Yush::SIZE_THUMB, $l->path);
                            // Create a thumbnail
                            // Kohana Image library
                            $thumbImage = Yii::app()->image->load($originalPath);
                            $thumbImage->resize(350, 350)->rotate(0)->quality(100)->sharpen(10);

                            // $thumbImage = PhpThumbFactory::create($originalPath);
                            // $thumbImage->resize(350, 350);

                            switch ($thumbImage->save($thumbPath)) {
                                case true:
                                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', self::MESSAGE_SUCCESS);
                                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->params->local . 'merchant/profile');
                                break;

                                default:
                                    # code...
                                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', self::MESSAGE_FAILURE);
                                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->params->local . 'merchant/profile');
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', self::MESSAGE_FAILURE);
                            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->params->local . 'merchant/profile');
                        }
                break;
        }
```

Does anybody have any idea what the problem might be??

Comment: Also, I have made sure that all folders are writable

Comment: I've used this before and never had this problem!

Comment: You mentioned the folders are writable but does the web server have write access to the folder? (though I would think you'd get a runtime error if that weren't the case). Also, not related to your question, but why are you using switch statements with methods that return true or false? An IF ELSE block would be much faster and easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Scott. I've actually just started playing around with coding and try to use new things whenever I can just to learn how they work etc. I've actually been on this server for a while and I've only started to encounter this problem since yesterday when I uploaded the new version of my site.

Comment: I have found the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. I place my protected folder one level above my public folder. Thus uploads get made to the same level as my protected folder and not my public one. I have attempted to fix this, with no success (This didn't happen before so I'm not sure why it's happening now).

Comment: Funny thing is that it uploads to the same level as my protected directory but then the YUSH retrieve helper looks for the image in the public folder. Ihave tried changing this line in the YUSH component : `public $baseDirectory = 'uploads';` to `public $baseDirectory = 'public_html/uploads';` . This then uploads to the right place but looks for the image in a directory above public_html